# Unable to display text from Rails ActiveRecord errors.full_message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

Ok, I've looked over results for this off and on all day (including search all over StackOverflow)...

In Rails 3.2.X and Ruby 1.9.3 I have a remote form. The form is working correctly and saving when valid, and not saving when not valid. However I can't get back the actual errors (and I've tried a bunch of different ways).

#### Here's the form (haml)

```
= form_for @lead, :remote => true, :validate => false do |f|
    .span6
        %ul
            %li
                = f.label "Name*"
                = f.text_field :name
            %li
                = f.label "Company*"
                = f.text_field :company
...
            %li
                = f.label :state
                = select_tag :state, options_for_select(us_states)
            %li
                = f.label "Email*"
                = f.text_field :email
    .actions
        = f.submit '', :id => "contactsubmit"
```

Here's the relevant spot in the controller:

```
def create
    @lead = Lead.new(params[:lead])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @lead.valid?
         format.js
        else
         format.js
        end
    end
end
```

#### And here's my view (create.js.erb) where I keep failing...

```
<% if @lead.errors.count == 0 %>
    $('#error_explanation').fadeOut(500);
    $('#learn-more .form').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#learn-more #form-response').fadeIn(500);
      });
<% else %>
      $('#error_explanation').fadeIn(500);
        <% @lead.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
           #never shows any messages. If I do @lead.errors.each do |error| 
           #it shows the field name, but not the body...?
           $('#error_explanation').append('<%=content_tag(:p, msg)%>');
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I know that commment isn't valid in there, I added it to show what I've tried.
I've tried a *million different ways* of showing the error message here. Everything else is working. I even added a counter in there (when not using msg) and it did show the four field errors. Any advice? Using similar code in another project (in a traditional view) w/o problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using `escape_javascript` anytime you run into troubles like this. Any quotes that might be inside the content or generated by a method like `content_tag` can break your JS.